# I'd tick you in all safe at night

Tags: meaning

Want the meaning of the above sentence in US english langauge

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't _tuck_ you in? That probably gives you better results in a dictionary. :)

Comment: It seems like something that officer Crabtree might say http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zGNVU5ZjlgA

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo, non-native speaker error, or deliberately quirky usage.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate phrase is "tuck in":

> [tuck in](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tuck+in) — To make (a child, for example) secure in bed for sleep, especially by tucking bedclothes into the bed.

Your example:

> I'd tuck you in all safe at night